# Substituir background-image de :after

Tags: jquery, css3

Tenho uma `div` com uma pseudo-classe `:after` onde eu crio um quadrado e coloco dentro uma figurinha de uma seta para baixo.

Estou tentando, com o código abaixo, ao clicar nessa `div` substituir a figurinha por outra semelhante:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
  contador = 0;
  $(".selectOption").click( function() {

      if(contador % 2 == 0) {
          $(".opcoes").css("overflow", "visible") ;
          $(".selectOption:after").css("background-image", "url(_imgs/setaBaixo.jpg)");
      } else {
           $(".opcoes").css("overflow", "hidden");         
          $(".selectOption:after").css("background-image", "url(_imgs/setaCima.jpg)");
      }

      $('.opcoes li').click(function(){ $($(this).closest('ul')).prepend($(this)); })

      contador++;
  }); 


  $("#select > option").each(function() {
      $(".opcoes").append("<li id="+this.value+">"+this.text+"</li>");
  });

});
```

Mas a figura não substitui.

Answer (score 0):

Você não pode alterar o pseudo-elemento `:after` porque tecnicamente ele não faz parte do DOM, portanto é inacessível via JavaScript (jQuery). O que você pode fazer é adicionar novas classes ao `:after`:

**Classes CSS com os backgrounds:**

```
.selectOption.setaBaixo:after{
    background-image: url(_imgs/setaBaixo.jpg);
}

.selectOption.setaCima:after{
    background-image: url(_imgs/setaCima.jpg);
}
```

**Código:**

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
  contador = 0;
  $(".selectOption").click( function() {

      if(contador % 2 == 0) {
          $(".opcoes").css("overflow", "visible") ;
          $(this).addClass("setaCima").removeClass("setaBaixo");
      } else {
           $(".opcoes").css("overflow", "hidden");         
          $(this).addClass("setaBaixo").removeClass("setaCima");
      }

      $('.opcoes li').click(function(){ $($(this).closest('ul')).prepend($(this)); })

      contador++;
  }); 


  $("#select > option").each(function() {
      $(".opcoes").append("<li id="+this.value+">"+this.text+"</li>");
  });

});
```

O snippet abaixo altera a cor, mas tem o mesmo efeito para imagens:

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {
  contador = 0;
  $(".selectOption").click( function() {

      if(contador % 2 == 0) {
          $(".opcoes").css("overflow", "visible") ;
          $(this).addClass("setaCima").removeClass("setaBaixo");
      } else {
           $(".opcoes").css("overflow", "hidden");         
          $(this).addClass("setaBaixo").removeClass("setaCima");
      }

      $('.opcoes li').click(function(){ $($(this).closest('ul')).prepend($(this)); })

      contador++;
  }); 


  $("#select > option").each(function() {
      $(".opcoes").append("<li id="+this.value+">"+this.text+"</li>");
  });

});
```

```css
.selectOption:after{
 content: '';
 display: block;
 width: 20px;
 height: 20px;
 background: red;
}

.selectOption.setaBaixo:after{
 background: blue;
}

.selectOption.setaCima:after{
 background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="selectOption">
Clique em mim!
</div>
```